# Where can I change the value for direct_url privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, static-block, cookie, variables

Although I can edit the **cookie_restriction_notice_block** to change the link to the relevant Privacy Policy page I would like to be able to change the value of `{{store direct_url="privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode"}}`.

I can't see anywhere to update it in the back-end and can't find it in core_config_data table.

Any ideas where it is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Cms->Pages` and look for the page with the identifier `privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode`.
Edit it and change the identifier.

Comment: And now I understand how direct_urls work :) Many thanks Marius