# How to change the value "privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode"?

Tags: magento2

How can I change the value of **privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode** link to a link of my choice? I am using Magento 2.3.2. I saw this [Magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182433/where-can-i-change-the-value-for-direct-url-privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mo) but I do not have such page. Is there something I am missing or did wrong?

Comment: do you want to change URL of `privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode` ?

Comment: Yes just the url.

Comment: did you tried my solution ?

Answer (score 4):

You can copy the cookie notice template to your own theme and change the URL according to your needs.

According to [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/226753/35679) you can copy the template from this file:

`vendor/magento/module-cookie/view/frontend/templates/html/notices.phtml`

to your own theme:

`app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Cookie/templates/html/notices.phtml`